# How to use vue-tel-input-vuetify in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js, vue-tel-input

I have been trying to use [vue-tel-input-vuetify](https://github.com/yogakurniawan/vue-tel-input-vuetify) in Nuxt and I have been having the issue as it is in the image below, I have also tried all the solutions in this link [Github](https://github.com/yogakurniawan/vue-tel-input-vuetify/issues/3) but I get the same error.

After installation, I created a plugin file **plugins/vue-tel-input-vuetify.js** and added the following code to it.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueTelInputVuetify from 'vue-tel-input-vuetify'
Vue.use(VueTelInputVuetify)
```

After that, I added this to **nuxt.config.js**

```
plugins: [
    '~/plugins/vue-tel-input-vuetify',
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-google-charts', mode: 'client' }
  ]
```

Between my component's script tags, I did this:

```
import { VueTelInputVuetify } from 'vue-tel-input-vuetify'

export default {
  components: {
    VueTelInputVuetify,
  },
...
```

And between my component's template tags I added this:

```html
<VueTelInputVuetify
  ref="phoneInput"
  v-model="phoneNumber"
  hint="Enter your phone number..."
  :rules="phoneNumberRules"
  placeholder=""
  label="Phone"
  :required="true"
  :validate-on-blur="true"
  :input-options="{showDialCode: true, tabIndex: 0}"
  :valid-characters-only="true"
  mode="international"
/>
```

[image: ssues]

Comment: Can you show us some code please? Hard to debug with just this.

Comment: What's around the `<VueTelInputVuetify/>` component?

Comment: I wrrapped it around `<client-only>` tag but, still the same error

Comment: And what about `{ '~/plugins/vue-tel-input-vuetify', mode: 'client' }`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too, it didn't work `{ src: '~/plugins/vue-tel-input-vuetify', mode: 'client' }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Updated answer

I've tried it myself, working perfectly fine with:

- Nuxt at `2.15.7`
- `@nuxtjs/vuetify` at `1.12.1` (`vuetify` at `2.5.7`)
- `vue-tel-input-vuetify` at `1.3.0`.

[image]

Had to write this in my `phone-input` plugin

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import vuetify from "vuetify";
import VueTelInputVuetify from 'vue-tel-input-vuetify/lib';

Vue.use(VueTelInputVuetify, {
  vuetify,
});
```

And I've imported it like this in `nuxt.config.js`

```js
plugins: ['@/plugins/phone-input'],
```

With the following template

```html
<template>
  <vue-tel-input-vuetify v-model="phone"></vue-tel-input-vuetify>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      phone: ''
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Here is a working [github repo](https://github.com/kissu/so-vuetify-tel-input) if you want to try it out by yourself.

---

#### Alternative idea

Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/yogakurniawan/vue-tel-input-vuetify), it says that you need to transpile it (for Vue).

In `nuxt.config.js`, you could try the following to replicate the same need

```js
build: {
  transpile: [
    'vue-tel-input-vuetify',
    // 'vuetify' // this one may also be needed, try with and without
  ],
}
```

Comment: @KoikiDamilare updated with a more in-depth solution, no `transpile` needed.

Comment: Above works for me as long as plugin set to client only...
plugins: [{
    src: '@/plugins/phone-input', mode: 'client'
  }],

Comment: just curious, why that does not work using camel case ? VueTelInputVuetify

Comment: @NelsonLaRocca should be. Check in your vue devtools how this is interpreted. Also, how do you write it exactly? Check the style guide for it: https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-name-casing-in-templates-strongly-recommended